# Read and edit contents of a huge number of XML files into POSTGRESQL

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a huge number of XML files and need to edit them.
I'm using this code to read import them but get an error.

```
SELECT
    XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(
        pg_read_binary_file('C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data/xmls/test'), 'UTF8'));
```

The error says:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff

And I think it's because my XML files start with this:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`

Any idea how to read UTF-16 XML files?

I even tried this:

```
SELECT
    XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(
        pg_read_binary_file('C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data/xmls/test'), 'UTF8'));
```

But doesn't seem to be right and working.

Comment: There's obviously something in the XML that can't be converted to UTF-8, which the error message says pretty clearly. If it can't be converted to UTF-8, you're going to either have to fix the XML content or import it as UTF-16. We can't see the XML file content, because it's not in your post, so we can't tell you what needs to be changed.

Comment: Are you sure your files don't start with a Byte Order Marker?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support `UTF-16` at all. The XML files must be converted to `UTF-8` without [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) before being imported.